# Ios разработка, клиент-сервер

Tags: php, python, ios, objective-c, swift

Насколько я понимаю objective-c, swift делают клиентскую часть приложения. А чтобы реализовать взаимодействие с сетью, бд, нужен серверный язык - php, python, ruby. Нужно ли учить один из этих языков?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что оффтопик

Comment: на свифте можно написать отличный сервер

Comment: например duolingo  на swift'е

Answer (score 1):

А как вы будете писать на серверном языке, если вы его не будете учить? Наугад вставлять различные комбинации букв? Это логично, чтобы использовать язык, его нужно знать :)

Обычно пишут **API**, которое реализуется на одном из серверных языков (backend), могут использовать REST подход, как наиболее частый вариант, а могут реализовать собственный протокол.

**К серверным языкам программирования можно отнести**: PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby, любой .NET язык программирования (технология ASP.NET), Java, Groovy и другие языки, возможность которых сводится к прослушиванию порта и обработке входящих запросов. Какой язык начинать учить и т.д. дело вкуса и никто вам лучше ваших предпочтений не подскажет.